# How do I put username into email when send mail to role in Rules?

Tags: rules

I'm using Rules 7.x-2.11 and create new rules. I created additional fields in profile and when user select there from option list he got a new role.
Next, i created new rule. When create new node with certain type drupal send mail to all users with this role.

EVENT
Node insert

CONDITIONS
Node is of type

ACTIONS
Mail to users of role

It works, but i need put in email text username. In data selector i have only "node" and "site" selector's, how can i get "account" selector?

Answer (score 0):

add [rules conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional), now in actions you can add more conditions, in actions fetch entity by id, node-author, drill until you find UID, add a conditional, add an if, entity has field, entity-fecthed-author-by-id, select your field, now you have what you need, repeat as needed, for every field, a conditional, an if and your field. done.
Your rule will look something like this:
[image]